# Change database based on request origin

Tags: c#, .net, database, api, asp.net-web-api

I am developing a web application which will be run by multiple companies. Each company will have its own instance of that web application. And each company has its own database (the web applications and databases will be running on the same server).

Each of these instances should be talking to one single Web API application to retrieve data from their database for that specific company.

Now I am wondering whether it is a good practice to change the database connection string in the Web API application based on the request origin? Or am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are things that need to be clarified:

1. How do you know which database to use based on the request?
2. What kind of technology do you use for db communication?
3. What do you mean by saying that you want to change Web API connection string based on the request origin? And where?

Anyways, the application is pretty funny. You need to have a connection string factory that returns connection string based on your request. You will need to decide where to put your connection string. Database or maybe some config settings?

Alternatively you can consider hosting your WebAPI with ASP.NET web sites and have different connection string for each tenant. This would also work unless you don't want to share database connection string with people who have access to websites.

Comment: Thank you for answering. (1. I though I could just map the connectionstring to a web domain address. (2. I use Entity Framework in .NET Web API. (3. As soon as a request comes in the Web API application, I want to check where the request comes from, and based on that knowledge send retrieve to correct data from the database that corresponds to the address the request comes from.

Comment: @Johannes in your case I would add a header that every website should add to web api request. The header would be mapped to an appropriate connection string. This is the most reliable approach. But you should also think about your data security. What if someone take header of other tenant and use it to damage your data. are you ready for it?